# Cookie value is returned as undefined

Tags: remix.run

I'm using cookie storage session to hold user's token which is received from authentication. When I'm trying to set it after login and call it from the root.tsx's Loader Function, the userId is returned as undefined.

My loader function is:

```
export let loader: LoaderFunction = async({request, params}) => { 
  let userId = await getUserId(request);
  console.log(userId);
  return (userId ? userId : null);
}
```

The function which I receive the userId getUserId is defined as:

```
export async function getUserId(request: Request){
  let session = await getUserSession(request);
  let userId = session.get("userId");
  if (!userId || typeof userId !== "string") return null;
  return userId;
}
```

The getUserSession function is as:

```
export async function getUserSession(request: Request){
  return getSession(request.headers.get('Cookie'));
}
```

I receive the getSession from destructring createCookieSessionStorage.

I'm creating a cookie with createUserSession function which is like:

```
export async function createUserSession(userId: string, redirectTo: string){
  let session = await getSession();
  session.set("userId", userId);
  return redirect(redirectTo, {
    headers: {
      "Set-Cookie": await commitSession(session),
    },
  });
}
```

I also receive the commitSession from destructing createCookieSessionStorage. I used the same code from the Jokes demo app.

```
let { getSession, commitSession, destroySession } = createCookieSessionStorage({
  cookie: {
    name: "RJ_session",
    secure: true,
    secrets: [sessionSecret],
    sameSite: "lax",
    path: "/",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    httpOnly: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You configured the cookie to have `secure: true`, this makes the cookie only work with HTTPS, while some browsers allow secure cookies in localhost most don't do it so that may be causing your cookie to not be saved by the browser, making subsequent requests not receive the cookie at all.